# Babel can't properly extend Array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to extend the Array in native JS. But not just modifying the prototype. I thought I'd give it a shot with the new `class` es2015 syntax.

Trying it out native (chrome already supports it - yay ヽ(´▽｀)ノ) and it all works just fine. Switching over to Babel for better support, it stops working. After trying a bit, I saw, that none of the methods are available on the new Object. Test code:

```
class CustomList extends Array {
  constructor(...elms) {
    super(...elms);

    this.testprop = "test";
  }

  customMethod(a) {
    console.log(a, this);
  }
}
```

[(test in babel)](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=true&spec=false&playground=false&code=class%20CustomList%20extends%20Array%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(...elms)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(...elms)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20this.testprop%20%3D%20%22test%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20customMethod(a)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(a%2C%20this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20list%20%3D%20new%20CustomList(1%2C2%2C3)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(list%20instanceof%20CustomList)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(list.customMethod%2C%20list.testprop)%3B%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20produces%20%22list.customMethod%20is%20not%20a%20function%22%20error%0A%2F%2F%20list.customMethod(%22test%22)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%22%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%22))

Comment: See https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/#classes

Comment: @unlucky13 seems like I'm a bit... unlucky? 

Thanks for the comment. That seems like it's it. Mind adding it as an aswer so I can accept it? Thanks"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Babel.js can't extend the built-in classes properly:

> Built-in classes such as `Date`, `Array`, `DOM` etc cannot be properly subclassed due to limitations in ES5 (for the `es2015-classes` plugin). You can try to use `babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend` based on `Object.setPrototypeOf` and `Reflect.construct`, but it also has some limitations.
>
> -- https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/#classes